# How to convert a multiple join on same table to a spring boot JPA specification?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

Please some help converting the the sql query below to a JPA specification.

```
select ud.id, ud.user_name, uoa_user.organization_id
from user_details ud
       inner join user_organization_access uoa_user on ud.id = uoa_user.user_id
       inner join user_organization_access uoa_org on uoa_user.organization_id = uoa_org.organization_id
       inner join role r on r.id = uoa_org.role_id
where uoa_org.user_id = '5e2f370f-cb53-4064-b8c1-3313d00b8a76'
  and r.name= 'InformationManager'
order by ud.user_name;
```

Some background pseudo java code snippets:

```
class User { 
  UUID id;
  @OneToMany Set<UserOrganizationAccess> userOrganizationAccess
}

class UserOrganizationAccess {
  String name;
  Role role: 
  Organization organization;
}


class Organization {
  UUID id;
  @OneToMany Set<UserOrganizationAccess> userOrganizationAccess
}

class Role {
 String name;
}
```

So the idea is: A user has Access to an organization with a certain role through an UserOrganizationAccess entry.

The Query  is to retrieve all users that have access to the organizations to which the specified user in the 'where' has access with the specified role

I came up with something like this:

```
    public static Specification<User> usersInRelatedOrganizationSpecification(@NonNull User user, @NonNull Role role) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            var userJoin = root.join(User_.userOrganizationAccess);
            var organizationJoin = userJoin.join(UserOrganizationAccess_.organization)
                    .join(Organization_.userOrganizationAccesses);

            return builder.and(
                    builder.equal(organizationJoin.get(UserOrganizationAccess_.USER), user),
                    builder.equal(organizationJoin.get(UserOrganizationAccess_.ROLE), role)
            );
        };
    }
```

but that generates the incorrect join, namely:

```
select user0_.id, user0_.user_name, userorgani1_.organization_id
from public.user_details user0_
       inner join public.user_organization_access userorgani1_ on user0_.id = userorgani1_.user_id
       inner join public.organization organizati2_ on userorgani1_.organization_id = organizati2_.id
       inner join public.user_organization_access userorgani3_ on organizati2_.id = userorgani3_.organization_id
where userorgani3_.user_id='5e2f370f-cb53-4064-b8c1-3313d00b8a76'
  and userorgani3_.role_id='6bdd7176-e08c-42ef-9f7b-ed4bbee3f1b2'
order by user0_.user_name;
```

I tried something like this:

```
    public static Specification<User> usersInRelatedOrganizationSpecification(@NonNull User user, @NonNull Role role) {
        return (root, query, builder) -> {
            var userJoin = root.join(User_.userOrganizationAccess);
            var organizationJoin = userJoin.join(UserOrganizationAccess_.organization)
                    .join(Organization_.userOrganizationAccesses);

            return builder.and(
                    builder.equal(organizationJoin.get(UserOrganizationAccess_.USER), user),
                    builder.equal(organizationJoin.get(UserOrganizationAccess_.ROLE), role)
            );
        };
    }
```

But that of course not work and the organizationJoin has wrong type to use in the where apart so hibernate complaints.

I am a bit stuck, I hope anybody can give me some pointers.

Comment: Nobody any ideas? Is the question clear enough?